# Output disappearing

Tags: c++

This is the code I was trying to make, its a simple structure program to store and search based on specific details instead of showing the entire structure every time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio>
#include <stdlib>

using namespace std;
struct stu
{
    int roll;
    char name[80];
    int cls;
    int adm;
};
void inp(stu &s)
{
    cout<<"\n Enter Details of Student: ";
    cout<<"\n Enter Name: ";
    gets(s.name);
    cout<<"\n Enter Roll no.: ";
    cin>>s.roll;
    cout<<"\n Enter Class: ";
    cin>>s.cls;
    cout<<"\n Enter Admission: ";
    cin>>s.adm;
}
void out(stu s)
{
    cout<<"\n Details Are: ";
    cout<<"\n Name: "<<'\t'<<s.name;
    cout<<"\n Roll: "<<'\t'<<s.roll;
    cout<<"\n Enter Class: "<<'\t'<<s.cls;
    cout<<"\n Admission No.: "<<'\t'<<s.adm;
}

void main()
{
    stu s[50];
    int n,i;
    cout<<"\n Enter no. of Students: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    inp(s[i]);
    }
    menu:
        clrscr();
    cout<<"\n Search by";
    cout<<"\n 1.Roll"<<'\t'<<"\n 2.Name"<<'\t'<<"\n 3.Admission No."<<'\t'<<"\n 4.Exit"<<endl;
    int opt,r,amd;
    char naam[30];
    cin>>opt;
    if(opt==1)
    {
         cout<<"\n Enter Roll:";
         cin>>r;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        if(s[i].roll==r)
           out(s[i]);
           else
            cout<<"\n Not Found";
        }
    }
    if(opt==2)
    {
        cout<<"\n Enter Name:";
        gets(naam);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(naam,s[i].name)==0)
                 out(s[i]);
                 else
            cout<<"\n Not Found";
        }
    }
       if(opt==3)
       {
         cout<<"\n Enter Admission No.: ";
         cin>>amd;
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
             if(amd==s[i].adm)
                 out(s[i]);
                 else
            cout<<"\n Not Found";
         }
       }
       if(opt==4)
        exit(0);
goto menu;

getch();
}
```

So even if I try to search using roll no or something no output is coming
after I try to search the window goes back to menu.  So how would I fix this?   Should I add a flag variable or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You definitely should add punctuation to your post, dude

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays are subject to buffer overrun errors.

Comment: Also you may(should) want to consider using proper loops and functions to replace `goto`.  In almost all cases one should not need to use `goto`.

Comment: Prefer not to cross streams.  Use `operator>>` for strings or, if you must use character arrays, `std::getline` for character arrays.  There is a possibility that `cin` and `gets` use different input mechanisms and buffers.

Comment: BTW, the `main` returns an `int`.  Always.

Comment: Where I am from, I am not allowed to use std::string and all cause its not been taught yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you loop back to your label you immediately clear the screen. So after you display your results you have no time to actually see them. You could try taking some input after the display and before the goto.

edit:
So like I said above, if you take some user input just before the goto statement, then the user will be able to read the printout before giving input. For example

```
cout >> "Please enter any character to continue.\n";
getch();
```

Then put your clrscr() function back where it was.

Also, I would echo what other people said in the comments. Mixing streams, using goto instead of built-in loops and using fixed-length arrays to store user input are all not too good.

Comment: So I removed clear screen altogether, and now I am getting the results but not everything starts to clutter up each time I search (you know cause there's no clear screen) so where will I put my clear screen now?